# Main activity opens every time on app startup

Tags: android

I am making a simple chat app with firebase sign in. Everything works great but one thing that bothers me is if a user is logged in, after starting the app it shows the login activity for a while before redirecting to the second second every time and it doesn't look good. Below are the screenshot for better understanding

[image]

This is the activity that is shown every time after the app is opened for 1-2 second even if the user is logged in

[image]

This is the logged in page

What I want is if a user is logged in and opens the app he should see the second activity directly

MainActivity (Login activity)

```
package com.example.fireapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthCredential;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText emailEditText;
    private EditText passwordEditText;
    private Button loginButton;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    private Button signInButton;
    private SignInButton googleButton;
    private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private String TAG = "Info";
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    int flag = 0;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    //firebase
    FirebaseUser user;
    String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        passwordEditText = findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        loginButton = findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
        signInButton = findViewById(R.id.signInButton);
        googleButton = findViewById(R.id.googleButton);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && flag != 1) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                    finish();
                }

            }
        };

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                login();
            }
        });
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, accountActivity.class));
                // finish();
            }
        });
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        googleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = 1;
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListner);
    }

    private void login() {
        String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in unsuccessful!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }

    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            userId = user.getUid();
                            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(userId);
                            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        finish();

                                    } else {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class));
                                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Google Sign in Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Main2Activity

```
package com.example.fireapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.fireapp.model.Users;
import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private View headerView;
    private TextView usernameText;
    private TextView emailText;
    private CircleImageView userImage;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    private DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        //toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("fireApp");

        //navigation drawer
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        //user details inside navigation drawer
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        usernameText = headerView.findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
        userImage = headerView.findViewById(R.id.userImage);
        emailText = headerView.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
        setUserDetails();
        if(savedInstanceState==null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new chatFragment()).commit();
            navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_chat);
        }

    }

    private void setUserDetails() {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(firebaseUser.getUid());
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               Users user= dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class);
                try {
                usernameText.setText(user.getUsername());
                emailText.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());

                    if (user.getImageUrl().equals("default")) {
                        userImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                    } else {
                        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageUrl()).into(userImage);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()){
            case R.id.nav_chat:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new chatFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_profile:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new profileFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_feed:
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new feedFragment()).commit();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_share:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Share!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_feedback:
                Toast.makeText(this, "Feedback!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }


        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

    //3 dots menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.logout) {
            AuthUI.getInstance()
                    .signOut(Main2Activity.this)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class));
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }

}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to save you from that is to create a [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences)

Assuming you created a preference for isLoggedIn then, inside your first activity that opens, the very first thing you do in onCreate is to check whether the user isLoggedIn. Then from there you can do if..else intent MainActivity or LoginActivity.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: After logging in, set a sharedpreference, now once you restart your app it always goes through that if-else condition

Answer (score 0):

Try to finish the activity once the user login

```
finish();
```

Then take back the user to the LoginActivity when he logs out

Comment: Did it inside the  `onAuthStateChanged ` block of main activity

Comment: You want auto-login the user if the user opens the app second time?

Comment: The user is getting auto logged. I want when a user opens the app for second time after logging  in he directly sees the main2activity rather than being redirected from mainactivity to main2activity

Comment: can you mention the flow of activity like Activity 1 --> Activity 2 --> Activity 3

Answer (score 0):

try this

The process that takes a login from an external service is not immediate, I recommend using an async task, so that while the login process is done, the above does not happen to you

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ....
    ....
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new loginTask().execute(true);
            }
        });
    }

}

class loginTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading", true);
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            dialog.dismiss();

            /** Redirect to main2 class **/
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
        /** Your code **/
              String email = emailEditText.getText().toString();
              String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
              if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                  progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              } else {
                mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sign in unsuccessful!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
          }

        }
}
```

Comment: To make it work better, you need to use it in an AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Rather then assigning listener you can do it like this

```
if(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) 
      startActivity(new Intent(LaunchScreen.this, LoginScreen.class));
else
      startActivity(new Intent(LaunchScreen.this, MainActivity.class));
finish();
```

Comment: I am getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try using finish() after the intent, this activity will be closed and therefore, will become also unreachable.